# Hausdorff Distance Between Convex Polygons

Tags: computational-geometry

I'm interested in calculating the Hausdorff Distance between 2 polygons (specifically quadrilaterals which are almost rectangles) defined by their vertices. They may overlap.

Recall $d_H(A,B) = \max(d(A,B), d(B,A))$ where $d$ is the Hausdorff semi-metric
$d(A,B) = \sup_{a\in A}\inf_{b\in B}d(a,b)$.

Is it true that, given a finite disjoint covering of $A$, $\{A_i\}$, $d(A,B)=\max\{d(A_i,B)\}$? A corollary of which is that $d(A,B)=d(A\setminus B,B)$.

I have found a paper by Atallah [1 (PDF)](http://docs.lib.purdue.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1362&context=cstech&sei-redir=1&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.co.uk%2Fscholar_url%3Fhl%3Den%26q%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fdocs.lib.purdue.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%253Farticle%253D1362%2526context%253Dcstech%26sa%3DX%26scisig%3DAAGBfm2KBgx4gRLwPm_PuNgeO-bP1KLiKA%26oi%3Dscholarr%26ei%3D87PRT4Ft6KPRBaGoua8E%26ved%3D0CAYQgAMoADAA#search=%22http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.lib.purdue.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1362%26context%3Dcstech%22). I'm interested in working in Python and would be open to any preprogrammed solutions.

Comment: Are you looking for a Python library which implements this algorithm, or do you want to write it yourself? Either way, consider posting in stackoverflow.com

Comment: I've posted to SO - someone suggested posting it here, though I already had!

Comment: The problem might be that you have two questions here - one about theory and one about its application. Regardless, could you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: I have an algorithm outputting a few almost rectangles, many of which are nearly the same - the vertices are +-5 pixels. I wish to cluster these similar rectangles and thought Hausdorff Distance is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it true that, given a finite disjoint covering of A, {Ai}, d(A,B)=max{d(Ai,B)}? A corollary of which is that d(A,B)=d(A∖B,B).

Yes, if $\cup A_i = A$. This follows from transitivity of comparison operators. It does not matter how you divide your points, $\max\{\sup A, \sup B\} = \sup A \cup B$.

Comment: Thanks, that means I can use an algorithm for (almost) disjoint polygons.

Comment: This is wrong. See the answer on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947366/hausdorff-distance-between-convex-polygons

Comment: This is not wrong. This difference is that you asked about $d$, while the stack overflow reply is referring to $d_H$.

Comment: Apologies. You are correct.